# How find \ in java regex?

Tags: java, regex

I want to find `????\??-??` string in `D:\it\2020\02-20\123\13.json`. `?` is a digit.

How Can I find it with java regex?

Comment: `"D:\it\2020\02-20\123\13.json".indexOf("2020\02-20")`

Comment: Use \\ in your regex it should work

Comment: pretty sure you are going to need to double backslash them

Comment: You must escape the backslash in java so you have `String backslash = "\\";` and when you want to use a backslash in regex you also have to escape it, therefore you need `String regex = "\\\\";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing a regex in java, we escape the `\` character with another backslash. So if you want to put one backslash character then you should do `\\` but if you want to escape the backslash then you do it with `\\\\`. Following regex should work fine in your case:

```
\\d+\\\\\\d+-\\d+
```

If you want to be specific then use:

```
\\d{4}\\\\\\d{2}-\\d{2}
```

- **[\d+\\\d+-\d+](https://regex101.com/r/lb3tiD/1)**
- **[\d{4}\\\d{2}-\d{2}](https://regex101.com/r/lb3tiD/2)**

Comment: I prefer to write `String regex = "[0-9]{4}\\\\[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}"` to reduce the amount of backslash, so its easier to not miss one.

Comment: @devpuh So according to you, just to prevent writing a backslash we should make it unreadable?

Comment: @roundAbout the only change is that `\\d` is replaced with `[0-9]` so that you no longer have `\\\\\\d`. _Wait was it `\\\\\\d` or `\\\\\d`, what does all the backslashes do?_

Comment: @devpuh It's so unnecessary. The one who can understand the use case of four backslash can also understand what is the use of six in a row. Your comment makes no sense.